# How to stop a Linux process for later execution swapping-out its memory

Tags: linux, process, swap, virtual-memory

I want to stop a long running process so it does not consume any CPU or physical memory resources, with the intention of resuming **the same process** in the future.

I know the CPU part is achievable using `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` [signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886812/whats-the-difference-between-sigstop-and-sigtstp) but is it possible to page-out (swap-out in the case of process dirty pages) **immediately** the private RSS memory of a (stopped) process?

Comment: What is the intention behind this? Do you want to ensure that the process resumes more quickly? Or do you want to prevent sensitive data to be written to disk? Or something else? If we know the intention, we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: The OS will do this automatically. There's really no reason to do anything specific.

Comment: @oliver I am creating a batch scheduler (https://github.com/brutusin/wava). The current implementation offers non-preemptive scheduling but I want to move to a preemptive one (being able of stop running jobs) to graceful avoid some deadlock situations when all running jobs depends on queued jobs. I need exactly the behavior asked, continuing stopped processes (not creating new ones from a checkpoint)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that is a risky assertion

Comment: @idelvall Then it sounds like you don't want to do anything special to memory.

Comment: I didn't feel necessary to give more details on my actual problem, furthermore I didn't want the question to sound like i wanted to promote my project but given your comments I can tell you that my scheduler main concern is to guarantee that running jobs memory doesn't never exceed physical memory limits in order to avoid paging and swapping. Stopping a running process without freeing its RSS memory would not    make room for other queued processes to start

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I forgot to mention you in my last comment. this is my real issue: https://github.com/brutusin/wava/issues/13

Comment: @idelvall Your question still makes no sense. You are asking how to force the paging out of memory while claiming that your objective is to avoid paging! Do you want to make sure to page everything or do you want to avoid paging things?

Comment: yes I expressed wrong, what i want is to avoid paging performed by the OS, especially for processes unmanaged by the scheduler.

Comment: Does `posix_fadvise(POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)` work on `/proc/<PID>/mem`?  [`vmtouch`](https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) might have a command-line option to do that, so you might not need to write code yourself to experiment.  (I'd suggest using `strace` to make sure `vmtouch` is making the system calls you expect.)  Does `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` work to trigger page-out of anonymous pages (easiest to try from within a running process, since madvise works on memory addresses, not file positions)?

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/128385/how-to-tell-linux-to-explicitly-swap-out-main-memory-of-a-suspended-process, but that doesn't have much of an answer.  It just suggests raising `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` to encourage the kernel to page out more aggressively.

Comment: I would look into the top answer on here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system

Answer (score 11):

You might look into a technique called checkpoint/restore.  This will allow you to take a running process and save its state to a set of files, then restore it at a later time.
To use it, start by installing the criu <sup>[[git](https://github.com/xemul/criu),[wiki](https://criu.org/Main_Page)]</sup> program (`yum install criu` or `apt install criu`).

To checkpoint a running process, create an empty directory to hold its files and cd into that directory.

```
mkdir /var/tmp/checkpoint
cd /var/tmp/checkpoint
```

Now checkpoint the running process.  In this case I'm using the --shell-job since I have my process running in a shell with an associated tty.

```
criu dump -t 404 --shell-job
```

404 is the pid of the process I want to checkpoint.  When I do this I see my running process get killed and my /var/tmp/checkpoint directory get populated with a set of files needed to restore it.

To restore the process, I make sure I'm in the directory with the checkpoint files and do a restore.

```
cd /var/tmp/checkpoint
criu restore --shell-job
```

The process will pick up where it left off in the terminal where this was run.  If I kill this running process and run `criu restore --shell-job` again, the process will revert back to the checkpoint and start up again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP claims they want to do. Try it -- there will be no reduction in memory used. It will just switch from process private memory to disk cache (due to writing out the set of files). It just makes an extra save step and an extra restore step, and the same memory is used (and ejectable) the same way. In fact, it may make things worse as some memory gets duplicated due to generating everything new to write out.

Comment: heh, good point @David, especially if `/tmp` is tmpfs (backed by memory/swap space).  If you checkpoint to a normal disk-backed filesystem, you can then use [`vmtouch -e`](https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/) to evict the pages from the pagecache, but it still uses extra RAM temporarily.  (Unless `criu` has an option to do direct i/o (with O_DIRECT)...)

Comment: It's hard to know if this is what the OP wants or not because the OP asks for a specific solution rather than explaining what problem he's trying to solve. This might be the perfect answer or it might be useless to him, we can't tell.

Comment: I have not looked at it in detail yet but, it seems that the restored process is a new process (different pId), and this is not exactly what i need...

Comment: @Peter, that's a really good point about /tmp using tmpfs on some installations.  I updated the solution to use /var/tmp instead.

Comment: @idelvall: That's how most flavours of checkpoint/restore work.  One major use-case is to save progress in a calculation across reboots.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah it makes sense for that scenario, but not exactly what i am looking for for mine